# Spock & Spock Reports: how "catch" and customize the error message for AssertionError?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, spock, spring-mvc-test, spock-reports

I am working with:

- Spock Core
- Spock Reports
- Spock Spring
- Spring MVC Testing

and I have the following code:

```
@FailsWith(java.lang.AssertionError.class)
def "findAll() Not Expected"(){

    given:

        url =  PersonaUrlHelper.FINDALL;

    when: 

        resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get(url)).andDo(print())

    then: 

        resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk())
                     .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))


}
```

Here the code *fails* (how is expected) because the method being tested really *returns* `(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` instead of `(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)`.

So that the reason of `@FailsWith(java.lang.AssertionError.class)`.

Even if I use `@FailsWith(value=java.lang.AssertionError.class, reason="JSON returned ...")` I am not able to see the `reason` through *Spock Reports*

**Question One**: how I can see the `reason` on *Spock Reports*?.

I know Spock offers the **thrown()** method, therefore I am able to do:

```
  then:
        def e = thrown(IllegalArgumentException)
        e.message == "Some expected error message"
        println e.message
```

Sadly *thrown* does not work for AssertionError.

If I use `thrown(AssertionError)` the test method does not pass, unique way is through `@FailsWith` but I am not able to *get the error message* from AssertionError

**Question Two** how is possible get the *Error Message* from AssertionError?

I know I am able to do something like

```
then: "Something to show on Spock Reports"
```

But just curious if the question two can be resolved..

Answer (score 1):

regarding **Question one**:

if you look at `FailsWithExtension#visitFeatureAnnotation` you can see that only value from the `@FailsWith` is evaluated, `reason` is not touched at all. What you could do is introduce you own type of annotation (custom one, e.g. same as `@FailsWith`) and override `AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension#visitFeatureAnnotation`. There you have access to `reason` parameter.

regarding **Question two**:

please look at this link: http://spock-framework.3207229.n2.nabble.com/Validate-exception-message-with-FailsWith-td7573288.html

additionally maybe you could override `AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension#visitSpec` and add custom listener (overriding `AbstractRunListener`). Then you have access to `AbstractRunListener#error` method whose documentation says:

> Called for every error that occurs during a spec run. May be called multiple times for the same method, for example if both
>      * the expect-block and the cleanup-block of a feature method fail.

Didn't test for **Question two**, but it may work. I've used sth similar.

Enjoy,

Tommy